# Programmatically Retrieve a PDF's security properties?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Is it possible to take a pre-existing PDF file and retrieve the security properties?
i.e. these:
[image: PDF Security Properties]

I have been reading through documentation for [ITextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=2) but I haven't yet found anything about opening a PDF object and then finding the Security properties.  Is this even possible via c#?

**UPDATE**

I have been playing around with [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1)

and have found that when loading up a new PDFDocument I can access properties via:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument("[pdf file here]");
Console.WriteLine(doc.SecuritySettings.PermitAssembleDocument);
```

However, regardless of the actual setting of that parameter (in my case, the Pdf does NOT have document assembly allowed)  the `SecuritySettings.PermitAssembleDocument` will still return true.

Am I reading this improperly, going about it improperly, or is it simply returning true because I can manipulate all those fields?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the [Docotic.Pdf Library](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can do this. If you look [here](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/help/permissions.aspx) you'll see that you can access permissions and flags through their Permissions.Flags property. I'm assuming this will give you access to what you are looking for.

Comment: I downloaded the evaluation license and have been playing around with `Docotic`.  However, what I am seeing is the same problem as with `PDFSharp`.  No matter what actual settings are in place on the PDF, it shows everything as Allowed.

Comment: That's too bad. Since you are saying both libraries are returning incorrect values, have you tried with another PDF? Could it be the PDF that you're working with? It sounds strange that two libraries aren't returning the right values.

Comment: I am trying another PDF, as we speak, though I agree that it is all suspicious.  The screenshot I attached above is from Adobe Acrobat X.  If I view same exact PDF file in Adobe Viewer, it shows that 3 different properties are marked as Not-Allowed.  This seems to be true, because when I attempt to extract content and convert the file, it gives an error that I have seen previously when dealing with disallowed permissions.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the `OwnerPassword` / `UserPassword` properties?  I am following through some of the documentation, but it is possible I am just not implementing something correctly?

Comment: That is a good question. If the PDF is protected by a password it could be that the library is returning a default value since it can't access the real values without opening the PDF using the password. Just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of open-source PDF Libraries in C#, Hope [this](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) helps